# JQuery slideshow from php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

i have this code which fetch all image with same id and storet in array 
and i want to display it as slideshow , right know the image display near to each other how can i use `Jquery` slide show

//PHP File (Server side)

```
<?php
 $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'images';

 $sql2 = "SELECT img FROM image WHERE L_ID=:id";
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->query('SET NAMES utf8');
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql2);  
    $stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET["L_ID"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $img = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    $con = null;
    echo '{"pics":'. json_encode($img) .'}'; 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}

?>
```

//js File

```
    $('#detailsPage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
        var id = getUrlVars()["L_ID"];
        $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getimage.php?L_ID=' + id, displayImg);
        });
    function displayImg(data) {





    var imgs = data.pics;
    console.log(imgs);
    for(var j=0;j<imgs.length;j++)
    {
        $('#pic').append('<img src="' + imgs[j].img + '"width=112 height=112/>');}

    $('#actionList').listview('refresh');

}

 function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [],
hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
 }
```

//Html

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: i am using rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js

Comment: Try the **[Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)**,  Hope the following fiddle will give you an idea http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/CPpBD/619/

Comment: mr zakaria , why its not working on phonegap app actually the slider appears and move without image , but in the laptop browser the image appears?

Answer (score 0):

following seems to work pretty well. But there is certainly much room for improvements.

I used the following: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

As I don't know, what you are doing with `$('#actionList').listview('refresh');` I commented it out.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>StackOverflow Question 42261254</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>StackOverflow Question 42261254</h1>

        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="dots-container" style="text-align:center"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'images';

$sql = "SELECT img FROM image WHERE L_ID=:id";
$data = array();

try
{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->query('SET NAMES utf8');
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET["L_ID"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $img = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    $con = null;

    $data['pics'] = $img;
    $data['success'] = true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

JS:

```
var slideIndex = 1;

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [],
        hash,
        hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    return vars;
}

function displayImg(data) {
    console.log(data);

    if (data.success) {
        var imgs = data.pics;

        console.log(imgs);

        for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
            $('.slideshow-container a.prev').before(
                '<div class="mySlides fade">' +
                    '<div class="numbertext">' + (j+1) + ' / ' + imgs.length + '</div>' +
                    '<img src="' + imgs[j].img + '" style="width: 100%"/>' +
                    '<div class="text">Caption Text</div>' +
                '</div>'
            );

            $('.dots-container').append(
                '<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(' + (j+1) + ')"></span> '
            );
        }

        //$('#actionList').listview('refresh');
        showSlides(slideIndex);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++) {
            console.error(data.errors[i]);
        }
    }
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    console.log(slides);
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = getUrlVars()["L_ID"];
    $.getJSON('getimage.php?L_ID=' + id, displayImg);
});
```

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: however when I run it in chrome, I get this javascript error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, i post the chrome error img on the top

Comment: Seems that the script doesn't find any slides with the class `mySlides`. The `img`'s that you add have to be inside a `div.mySlides`.

Comment: the image src inside the class myslides as you write , right?